# Unable to connect to HDFS from a worker/data node on a Kerberized cluster using pyarrow' hdfs API

Tags: hdfs, dask, pyarrow

Here's what I'm trying:

```
import pyarrow as pa

conf = {"hadoop.security.authentication": "kerberos"}
fs = pa.hdfs.connect(kerb_ticket="/tmp/krb5cc_44444", extra_conf=conf)
```

However, when I submit this job to the cluster using `Dask-YARN`, I get the following error:

```
  File "test/run.py", line 3
    fs = pa.hdfs.connect(kerb_ticket="/tmp/krb5cc_44444", extra_conf=conf)
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/10/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfsf6/appcache/application_1560931326013_183242/container_e47_1560931326013_183242_01_000003/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 211, in connect
  File "/opt/hadoop/data/10/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfsf6/appcache/application_1560931326013_183242/container_e47_1560931326013_183242_01_000003/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/hdfs.py", line 38, in __init__
  File "pyarrow/io-hdfs.pxi", line 105, in pyarrow.lib.HadoopFileSystem._connect
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: HDFS connection failed
```

I also tried setting `host (to a name node)` and `port (=8020)`, however I run into the same error. Since the error is not descriptive, I'm not sure which setting needs to be altered. Any clues anyone?

Comment: This may be a bug to report to pyarrow, but you should try to run the same connection from an edge node directly (i.e., in a console session, not a yarn worker) and look in the security/system logs to see what conditions got triggered.

Comment: @mdurant what are "security/system" logs?

Comment: Ones produced by hadoop central services (yarn resource manager, hdfs name server) and auth processes (krb, ldap ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the configuration and kerberos ticket are loaded automatically, and you should just be able to connect using

```
fs = pa.hdfs.connect()
```

alone. This does require that you have already called `kinit` (on worker nodes the credentials (but *not* the ticket) is transferred to the worker environment automatically, no need to do anything). I suggest trying with no parameters locally, then on a worker node.

Comment: Thanks @jiminy_crist!